# Weird behaving of pointers and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am new to C.

I am trying to take a char array (a string) and explode it to 2 strings by a delimiter. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char line_array[260];
    char *line = line_array;
    scanf("%s", line_array);
    char *line2 = strdup(line);
    char *command = strtok(line2, " "); // WORKS FINE = open
    printf("%s %c\n", command, *(line+4)); // PRINTS: open (prints only command, *(line+4) is empty)
    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve after I got the first part of the string (where it says "works fine = open") is to print all the chars from command_array[strlen(command)] to the end of the array, but nothing of what I tried worked.

Comment: A `char` is a small integral type of one byte, so `line_array[0]` is usually a number between 0 and 255 (when `char` is unsigned) or a number between -128 and 127 (when `char` is signed).

Comment: Can I convert it to an actual character?

Comment: What do you mean by "actual character"? A `char` is a small integral type! (and with UTF8 some glyphs are encoded in several bytes).

Comment: What does it mean about "expecting an integer"?Treating (char*)"123" to (dec)123?If that, you need to use 'atoi()'

Comment: Do you mean that the string contains textual representation of integers or what???

Comment: Please look at the updated code.

Comment: Thank you, used gets as MYMNeo answered and it worked.

Comment: @AdamGold, `gets` will cause overflow if your input string's length is bigger than the buffer size, so use `fgets` as instead. `gets(a)` is equal to `fgets(a, @buffer_size, stdin)`, CR/LF will be store in your buffer, treat it if you need

Comment: @AdamGold Even the man page says "**Never use gets()**". Don't use it, seriously. (And it's been removed from the language now, phew.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your new updating question and code, I finally know your problem.The problem is that your method of getting string, `scanf` read string into buffer, but it treats blank or CR/LF as a new start of new inputting.According to your want, you type "abcdefg 9", `scanf("%s"，value)` will only get `abcdefg` to value, and leave "9" in the stdin buffer.So you need to use `gets(value)` to get all your input, then `strtok`.

Comment: To quote the man page: "**Never use gets()**" - and they mean it. Thankfully, `gets()` has been removed from the standard library now (Yay C11!).

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
printf("%s\n", filename+4);
```

which prints the string filename from 5th char to end of string

%c prints only one char

*(filename+4) takes the 5th char code from string filename.

filename+4 gives the address of the 5th char of string filename

Comment: I know %c prints only one char, *(filename+4) is supposed to be one char so no need to try and print it as a string. filename+4 is empty.

Comment: You never do something with the command variable. What does the line `char *filename = line;` do? [strtok example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) Please give example input and output data

Answer (score 0):

In C's expressions all `chars` are implicitly converted to `ints` first. When `char` arguments are passed to variadic functions (like `printf()`) they are also implicitly converted to `ints`. But I'm not seeing a problem with that.

However, what I'm seeing is that `explodestr()` is missing a return statement returning a `char`, which is coincidentally an integer.

Comment: I am the debug stage so I didn't want to return anything from explodestr yet, because it just won't work. I can't get the second part of the string.

Comment: Then you need to elaborate your question because it's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to read one single line and split it at its first space character, you could try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char* line = NULL;
  size_t linesiz = 0;
  if (getline(&line, &linesiz, stdin) > 0) {
    char* space = strchr (line, ' ');
    if (space) {
       *space = (char)0; // to end the chunk before 
       printf ("first chunk is %s\n", line);
       printf ("after space have %s\n", space+1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to enable all warnings in your compiler and to learn how to debug. On Linux, that means compile with `gcc -Wall -g`  and use the `gdb` debugger.

BTW, if you know that all lines start with a word (without spaces), then some spacing character (like space, tab, return, newline, ...) then some integer, you could declare

```
int i=0;
char buf[30];
memset (buf, 0, sizeof(buf)); // zero the buf
```

then use

```
if (scanf("%30s %d", buf, &i)>=2) { /* do something with buf & i */ }
```

You many want to read the man page of `feature_test_macros(7)`

Comment: Getting some errors.. editor.c:13: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
Undefined symbols:
  "_getline", referenced from:
      _main in *******
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: `getline` is POSIX2008 and may need `_GNU_SOURCE` feature or a recent libc.

Comment: Still getting the undefined symbol of _getline.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your system, or you have a too old `libc` or `gcc`; or you need to pass `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to your `gcc`

Comment: You should consider upgrading your compiler and Linux distribution to something newer. GCC 4.2.1 was released in july 2007. A lot of progress has been made in standards (Posix2008), in the Libc library, in the GCC compiler since 2007. To learn C, don't use such old stuff. (and recent GCC are more standard conforming and gives more helpful warnings and better optimizations). Latest GCC is 4.7, and my Glibc is 2.13, my kernel a 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `strtok` in a loop. Set the first argument to NULL if you're parsing the same string. This will modify the string, but we have made a copy in this example to work with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line_array[260];
    char *line, *p;

    fgets(line_array, sizeof(line_array), stdin);
    line = strdup(line_array);

    p = strtok(line, " ");
    while (p) {
        puts(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your last line.....should be
`printf( "%s\n", ( line + 4 ) );`
and you are done what you are expecting.
**Reasons:**
**1.** %c can't print except a single character at once.
**2.** String always deal with the base address in C language, so you need to remove the asterisk too.
Hope your question is answered.